# How to find which one port is the actual port number of glassfish domain?

Tags: glassfish

```
<network-listeners>
              <network-listener protocol="http-listener-1" port="8080" name="http-listener-1" thread-pool="http-thread-pool" transport="tcp"></network-listener>
              <network-listener protocol="http-listener-2" port="8181" name="http-listener-2" thread-pool="http-thread-pool" transport="tcp"></network-listener>
              <network-listener protocol="pu-protocol" port="4848" name="admin-listener" thread-pool="admin-thread-pool" transport="tcp"></network-listener>      
  
</network-listeners>
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19879-01/821-0177/fxxov/index.html

According to this documentation, I need to see the http-listener port value. But there are 2 values for http-listener.

Likewise, in fact the glassfish admin runs from "ip address:4848"

I need to change password using this command, and I'm not sure what is the port number of the domain.

```
asadmin --port 5048 enable-secure-admin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the password, you cahnge that of admin port, that's the one that ends with 48.